# any parallax effect jumps with nicescroll in webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, webkit

I'm trying to achieve a smooth parallax effect. But it's not working on any webkit browsers like chrome/opera/safari. Even the problem is on IE. Only firefox doesn't have the problem.

I'm using nicescroll for smooth scrolling. Tried stellar, parallax.js and my custom javascript with jquery for parallax effect. All gives me same effect with the issue. When I scroll with mousewheel or keyboard, the parallax element jumps a few time just like a spring.

*** I have found a clue to this, this issue happens only when I make the parallax effect to the opposite direction of scrolling. If I make the effect on the same direction of scrolling, it goes smooth.

I have seen some other sites with nicescroll and parallax effect. I have checked their fps is about 30-40 and the parallax effect is so smooth in any browser. But my document has fps about 50+ but this problem is happening.
So, I think I need to do some css -webkit- hacks. Like backface-visibility fixed transform issues, is there any hacks for scrolling?

I have been checking other similar question on stackoverflow, but none of the answers helped me. So please don't kill this question by marking as duplicate.